# Curved shapes using CSS

Tags: css, css-shapes

In a world where layouts is nothing more than squares and grids, I found this layout concept and I tought that curved layer in the first section an amazing idea to create something different:

https://www.behance.net/gallery/28594475/Accrosport

But now I'm in doubt. How can I do it with css? Anyone has an idea in how to do it and recreate a simple example? I tried to recreate that using border-radius, but it got a bit strange:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpRQaZ

css:

```
.curved {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background-image: url('http://www.erikaalkblog.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/yoga2.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 250% 250% 250% 250% / 0% 0% 20% 20%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: .1em;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: _"But now I have a debut."_ What's that mean?

Comment: Your example looks pretty damn close to the same curve in the example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your example this is what they are using:

```css
.curved {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background-image: url('http://www.erikaalkblog.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/yoga2.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 7%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 7%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: .1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="curved"></div>
```

Comment: Hey Joel. First I want to say thanks for the reply. But note that in the corners the curves is greater.

Comment: @user3130064 this is the exact way they did on the website you've showed.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with css `clip-path` using `path.svg` file as a shape.

More on this https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/

Basic examples on http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Note that `clip-path` has not been implemented in IE http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

Good luck